# Transfer developing instance to live server procedure

Tags: 2013, deployment

I have been assigned the task to transfer a development Sharepoint instance to the production server. I am new to this project and there is no developer here to provide me with additional information and I have minimal experience in Sharepoint deployments.

There is a SharePoint 2013 instance installed in a VM and I must transfer it to the live SharePoint 2013 server.
I have already installed SQL 2012 and  SharePoint 2013 to the server and now i don't know how 
to start transferring the application to live. The application has some custom `Virtual WebParts` and `Excel PowerPivot`.

I haven't tried to transfer anything yet, can you provide me with some instructions of how to make this transfer and some reading material about that.

Comment: Deployment process varies according to the solution. While there are some basic steps that can be followed but you mentioned custom web parts and those might have their own specific configuration requirements. Can you ask the developers to send a deployment manual?

Answer (score 2):

Here are couple of points which can help you

1. Find all custom Solutions - For this you can open Central Administration -> System Settings -> Solutions
2. Now using PowerShell you can download those solutions from the Development Server

   `$farm = Get-SPFarm`
      `$file = $farm.Solutions.Item("solutionname.wsp").SolutionFile` 
      `$file.SaveAs("c:\path\solutionname.wsp")`
3. Now you can deploy and install these files into the Live Server using PowerShell

   `Add-SPSolution solutionname.wsp`
      `#Installing can be tuned to target particular Web Application & GAC Etc`
      `Install-SPSolution -Identity solutionname.wsp -GACDeployment`
4. [Web Application Backup from Dev](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748650(v=office.15).aspx)
5. [Restore the Backup to Live](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748647(v=office.15).aspx)